# A chord is drawn from a point $P(1, t)$ to the parabola $y^2 = 4ax$ which cuts the parabola at A and B. If $PA.PB = 3|t|$, then find the range of t.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

A chord is drawn from a point $P(1, t)$ to the parabola $y^2 = 4ax$ which cuts the parabola at A and B. If $PA.PB = 3|t|$, then find the range of t.

I was able to solve the question using parametric form of a line but wasn't able to figure out how to solve it geometrically using properties of parabola and similarity of triangles(if possible).

Comment: You should include your parametric solution. This could provide geometric insights without people having to duplicate your effort.

Comment: I think it will spoil people's solution's authenticity.

Comment: You're asking people for help. You should want to make things as easy as possible for them; conversely, actively withholding information to make them work harder is disrespectful of them and their time. (Note: You could always wrap the solution in [a spoiler box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1191) using `>!`.)  The least you could do is provide the range of $t$ so that responders know they aren't being asked to construct the seventeenth root of $e/\pi$ or something. (Knowing the answer can help people create, say, GeoGebra sketches to better understand the geometry of the problem.)

Comment: I just thought my method was too long and there should a much more elegant solution to this problem. I did not want to destroy people's new way of approaching this problem. Also, I didn't know about the spoiler box and will you with the range of t and idea of my approach ASAP.

Comment: My intention wasn't to scold, merely to instruct. :)  Don't worry about spoiling someone else's fresh approach; some of us launch into solutions without reading a question all the way through, anyway. (This is problematic when the question is specifically *"What did I do wrong?"* :)  Still, a glance at your work can convey how complicated/interesting a problem is, which is helpful. Withholding work can cause someone to spend a lot of time duplicating it, and possibly even posting it, only to have you respond "I already tried that." Not fun. :/  Anyway, the point is: Be mindful. ... Regards!